# Is "Given is .." right?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Source: https://www.dailymetalprice.com/aluminum.html

> The price of aluminum is based on the cumulative result of the
> previous trading session. *Given is* multitude of purposes and that many
> global industries use aluminum in their products, the price models the
> overall health of the world economy.

Is the "Given is .." here right?

My guess is it should be "Given its .." or the writer just omitted the word "there" before "is" but if so I do not know a rule for that.

Comment: Looks like a typo.  It should be "its" not "is".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the example sentence is not idiomatic. It appears to be a typo (the author wrote "is" instead of "its").

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question contained a **typo**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Given is** multitude of purposes and that many global industries use aluminum in their products, the price models the overall health of the world economy.

That sentence is wrong! The writer wanted to write the following sentence:

> **Given its** multitude of purposes and that many global industries use aluminum in their products, the price models the overall health of the world economy.

The writer got confused and made a mistake. The writer didn't omit the word **"there"** before the word **"is"**.

> **Given there is** multitude of purposes and that many global industries use aluminum in their products, the price models the overall health of the world economy.

That sentence is wrong. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your guess that the writer intended "Given its .." and that this is therefore a typographical error.
The "it" here being "aluminum" (or "aluminium" as we spell it here in UK).
The sentiment being "Given aluminum's multitude of purposes ..".